# A localization sequence for étale cohomology of $\mathcal O_K$, where $K$ is a local field

Tags: class-field-theory, local-field, etale-cohomology

Given a non-archimedean local field $K$, let $\mathcal O_K$ be the associated valuation ring and $k$ its residue field. According to [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/271898), we have short exact sequence

$$0 \to H^2(\mathcal O_K,\Bbb G_m) \to H^2(K,\Bbb G_m) \to H^1(k,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z) \to 0$$

I'm trying to see where this exact sequence comes from. The context is to compute the Brauer group of a local field, as is done in the linked answer.

Here are some thoughts: let $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal O_K)$ and let $i$ be the inclusion of the closed point and $j$ be the inclusion of the generic point. Then we are in the situation of section 5.5 from [these notes by Brunault](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/francois.brunault/enseignement/1819/etale_notes.pdf), so we get an exact sequence of étale sheaves (prop 5.29):
$$0 \to j_!j^*\Bbb G_m \to \Bbb G_m \to i_*i^* \Bbb G_m \to 0$$

This induces a long exact sequence of étala cohomology group, but it I'm not sure how to compute it.